# Changing the value of a select box option and selecting it in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, html-select, casperjs

I am trying to circumvent some difficult query result pagination by hijacking a form element that controls the number of query results shown on a page.  When I've tested my Javascript modification in the Firebug console against the live site it works like a champ but when the same Javascript is injected into the DOM via the casper.evaluate method I get inconsistent results.

My code is as follows:

```
var s = document.getElementById("requisitionListInterface.dropListSize");
s.options[4].value = 1000;
s.options[4].selected = true;
var e = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
e.initEvent("change", false, true );
setTimeout( function(s, e){ s.dispatchEvent(e); }, 2000, s, e );
```

I've had to create then event handler 'e' and attach it to element 's' to in order to replicated what was taking place on the form (submit page when select.change occurred).

Again the above code functions as expected in Firefox every time.

Comment: Give it a go in a WebKit browser such as Chrome. PhantomJS is based on WebKit afterall. If it works in a WebKit browser you may have to provide the page you're using so others can give it a go as well.

Comment: Or try using Arora, which uses the same version of Webkit and js engine than PhantomJS http://code.google.com/p/arora/

Answer (score 0):

If the select box is firing Ajax you may not be giving the browser enough time to get the results.  I would put some wait statements in there to give things enough time to find and execute.